Jest running failed: Unexpected token 'export'
I'm trying to run my tests using jest and I keep facing this error
    Details:

    /Users/mamad/repos/New Mindro-ai/mindro-dev/web-client/node_modules/react-markdown/index.js:9
    export {Markdown as default, defaultUrlTransform} from './lib/index.js'
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

I tried adding transformIgnorePatterns to my jest config file. Here's my jest.confing.js file:
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const config = {
  coverageProvider: 'v8',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],

  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!react-markdown/)']
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(config);

Also, here's my babel.config.js file:
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
};

Based on the previous answers on the web, the transformIgnorePatterns should work, but its doesn't. I'm totally confused.
